# How can I check in Rules if the number of members is below 50 or not?

Tags: users, rules, userpoints

I need to add some user points to users when they signup to the site. Using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module I already provided that functionality. But problem is to add some less points after 50 members have signed up.

So how can I implement a condition to differentiate the people that are registered:

- first 50 members means `Sign-up (first 50 = 20,000)`.
- after 50 members add `3000 points to user signup` .

Anyone suggestions?

Comment: What event are you using in the rules. I mean, Are you assigning points in the rules for the new registered user or assigning points to a bulk of users (all users at once)?

Comment: "After saving a new user account" here i used this event for assigning points to newly created users

Answer (score 1):

You need get the count of the total users so far from the users table.
To do that, you can use a condition with php code where you have to write a `db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users"); //[not tested]`

if result gets number of existing users. you can return true/false to go to the action in order to assign points.

Let me know if you got it working.

Comment: where i have to write this condition?

Comment: As you are using rules, for any rule set there is an event, condition and action. The approach need to be flexible based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work by using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) in combination with the [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module, as further detailed below.

#### Step 1

Use the [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module to create a view of all your users, in which you add a VBO field to it. Simply include a field like `uid` for each user (no need for any other fields). Just make sure you get exactly 1 row for each user you want to take into consideration (eg: also count `user/1`?).

#### Step 2

Create a 1st Rules Component with a Rules Condition "***Check number of results returned by a VBO view***". And select the VBO view created in the previous step. If the number of results is 50 or less, then perform a Rules Action (in that Rules Component) to grant 20,000 points (similar to what your current rule already does).

#### Step 3

Create a 2nd Rules Component which is similar to the Rules Component from Step 2, but in this component the logic is like so: if the number of results is 51 or more, then perform a Rules Action (in that Rules Component) to grant 3,000 points.

#### Step 4

Replace your existing Rule like so:

- Keep the same **Rules Event** (= when users signup to the site).
- Don't use any **Rules Conditions** (there is no need for them in this rule).
- Perform 2 **Rules Actions**:

  - Execute the Rules Component from Step 2.
  - Execute the Rules Component from Step 3.

***Done!***